# How can I change content of my app after it is published without updating version?

Tags: android, web-applications, android-developer-api

I want to make an android app that will display mess menu of hostel. The menu will be changing every week so how can I change content of TextView once it is installed in user's phone  .I considered WebView but I want better alternative . I think I need some cloud based service here . What are some good resources to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a Simple REST API and then every time you start your app call your api to retrieve the information, for example
yourdomaing.com/api/menu/getmenus should retrieve a Json with every item on menu.

You have plenty languages for making a simple rest api

check this related link

[Examples of REST APIS](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/3432056-build-your-web-projects-with-rest-apis/3496011-examples-of-rest-apis)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be Firebase (by Google).
It's a free and real-time service. It allows you to change the content while the app is running. See "real-time database" and "A/B testing" in Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data (Text/Media) on firebase,It is very easy to start and then enable firebase offline functionality so that it is not required to download data on each launch of application.
Update data on firebase and add valueEventListener in your activity to get that data.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of firebase.  Should I use storage or database feature of firebase for updating menu.

Comment: We use the firebase database if our data is only text and firebase database+storage if data is some form of media i.e. Images/video/audio etc